# Setting Python Path in VS Code in Windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

I'm trying to import some local modules in Python while using VS Code as my editor. Something like this:

```
import folder1.subfolder2.program3
```

We'll say "folder1" is located at 'C:/folder1'

VS Code does not recognize this and I keep getting failed import statements. It instead thinks 'C:/folder6' (for example) is the path. How can I change the Python Path in VS Code?

I tried changing the PythonPath in Environment Variables and that didn't fix the problem. I know there is a launch.json file in VS Code I can create by debugging. Can I set the PythonPath there and how would I do it?

**Edit:** Some updates. I can manually add a PythonPath to a file like this:

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += os.pathsep + "C:\\folder1\\etc"
```

This is fine for running 1 file, but I often have dozens of interconnected files and don't want to add that line to every single one.

I also tried adding a launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal", 
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "C://folder1//etc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

That doesn't seem to be changing anything, though, when I run a .py file from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the Python extension you want it to look for code outside of your current workspace. You can either add a [`"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense) or create a [`.env` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) and set your `PYTHONPATH` there.

Comment: I agree. Create a file name '.env' under the project, type in: "PYTHONPATH=D:\workPlace\javatest;D:\workPlace\springboot", you will add two "PYTHONPATH" variables. you can refer to  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file for more information. And this path depends on the default setting "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env". So you can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but on vs code there is a python button on the bottom left that allows me to change the python path. The button says python3.8.1... I only code python, so you may have to have a .py file open or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

**VS Code** only search on python path that is in status bar (PYTHON_PATH/lib/*) and directory of file that you are working not anywhere else (I couldn't find any setting to change this path).
[VS Code Statusbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wYZG.png)

(So I recommend to put your package in PYTHON_PATH/lib)

Also this thing that you're saying (folder1.folder2/mypackage) is only possible if you put `__init__.py` in each of directories

if you put your folder in directory of your file, tree of your working directory should be something like this:

```
cwd
|____ __init__.py
|____ folder1
      |____ __init__.py
      |____ subfolder2
            |____ __init__.py
            |____ program1.py
```

*In this situation I think I would do this:*

You can copy `C:/folder1/folder2/mymodule.py` to your file_path, then try to import it with      `import mymodule`. See code below:

```
import rx7
rx7.files.copy('C:/folder1/folder2/mymodule.py', 'mymodule.py')
import mymodule
```

Comment: Yes, I used __init__.py for each folder. I should've specified that.

Comment: Aha That's OK. But as I said there is no setting for this and reason is when you want to execute your script, it only import modules from python_path and file_path, So VS Code do not add this feature to the app